Can you patent a combination of native bacteria?
Can you patent the usage of a combination of bacteria to fulfill a purpose like air purification?

I am not a lawyer. You cannot patent a naturally occurring organism. You might be able to patent the use of one or more organisms to fulfill a purpose. This is done all the time in medical products where, for example, organisms are used to generate antibodies for diagnostics. So, with your example, I don't think you can patent a combination of bacteria. You can patent the use of those bacteria in a system purify air assuming the system otherwise meets the requirements for patentability.

If the combination is not found in nature and the effect of the combination is greater/different in a synergistic way than the sum of the properties of the bacteria, and is useful, it might fly.
There is a famous case of a combination of materials that just had the properties of each of the ingredients. It was ruled not patentable.
